# looping throug List and deleting not working

Tags: java

Code:

```
List<InData> inDataList= generateInRepo.getInList();
for(int i=0; i<inDataList.size();i++){
    if(somecondition){
        inDataList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

the problem here is when an item is removed the size of list gets disturbed and code fails. How to acheive this functionality in right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you should not increment `i` after deletion.

The trick to deleting from the list that you iterate is iterating it backwards:

```
for( int i=inDataList.size()-1; i <= 0 ; i--) {
    if(somecondition){
        inDataList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

This way your next iteration will never come to the index that you have visited already.

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator.remove()` is safe during iteration:

```
List<InData> inDataList = generateInRepo.getInList();

Iterator<InData> it = inDataList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   InData data = it.next();
   if (some condition) {
     it.remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Iterator`

```
List<InData> inDataList = generateInRepo.getInList();
for (Iterator<InData> iterator = inDataList.iterator(); iterator
        .hasNext();) {
    InData inData = (InData) iterator.next();
    if (somecondition) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy 'good' records to another array, then replace original one.

Comment: Well, general practice in any programming language is: don't change original array if you need to remove records, work on copy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Iterator` and try to remove element from List.

```
for(Iterator<InData> itr = inDataList.iterator();itr.hasNext();itr.next();) {
    if(somecondition) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```